# run time error when Casting (down casting) a type to another subType

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, downcast

in numerous other Types I have created it is possible to downCast a type 
and i usually Create An Extension method too so it will be easier to manage...

```
BaseTypeM
BTDerV : BaseTypeM
BTDerLastDescndnt : BTDerV
```

now i create A LastDerived Type and assign its value To ParentType

```
BTDerV BTDer;

BTDerLastDescndnt BTDerLastDesc = new BTDerLastDescndnt(parA, ParB);


this.BTDer = BTDerLastDesc;
```

then using the downCast Extension

```
var LDesc = this.BTDer.AsBTDerLastDescndnt();
```

which is actually

```
public static BTDerLastDescndnt AsBTDerLastDescndnt(this BTDerV SelfBTDerV )
{
    return (BTDerLastDescndnt)SelfBTDerV;
}
```

now when i do this as the code below,  here it does compile but gives me a run-time error

```
        //BTDerV---v                 v---BaseTypeM
 public class SqlParDefV : SqlParameterM
 {
     public override SqlSpParDefMeta ParDMT
     {
         get { 
             return base.ParDMT;
         }
         set {
             base.ParDMT = value;
         }
     }
    public SqlParDefV(int bsprpOrdinal, string bsprpParName, MSSTypesS bdprpTypeS, bool bsprpIsDbStuctured, bool bsprpIsReq = true, ParameterDirection bsprpDirection = ParameterDirection.Input)
    {
        this.ParDMT = new SqlSpParDefMeta(bsprpOrdinal, bsprpParName, bdprpTypeS, bsprpIsReq, bsprpIsDbStuctured, bsprpDirection);
    }

}


       //BTDerLastDescndnt---v
public sealed class SqlParTvDrecDefinitionVScl : SqlParDefV
{
    public override SqlSpParDefMeta ParDMT
    {
        get {
            return base.ParDMT;
        }
        set {
            base.ParDMT = value;
        }
    }
    public SprocTvTargetSF.currentSDTObjType SqlObjType { get; set; }
    public SqlMetaData[] Meta { get; set; }

    public SqlParTvDrecDefinitionVScl(int bsprpOrdinal, string bsprpParName, SprocTvTargetSF.currentSDTObjType ctrSqlObjType, SqlMetaData[] parGeneratedSqlMetaData, MSSTypesS bdprpTypeS, bool bsprpIsDbStuctured, bool bsprpIsReq = true, ParameterDirection bsprpDirection = ParameterDirection.Input)
                        : base(bsprpOrdinal, bsprpParName, bdprpTypeS, bsprpIsDbStuctured, bsprpIsReq, bsprpDirection)
    {
        this.SqlObjType = ctrSqlObjType;
        this.Meta = parGeneratedSqlMetaData;
    }
}
```

is there something unusual here or am i confused and missed some basic rule ?

Comment: Not compile is a __compile error__ not a __runtime error__ which occurs during the runtime of a program

Comment: @BenKnoble i don't understand , it does compile but on runtime, in `AsSqlParTvDrecDefinitionVScl()` it runs till body of the method then it gives **runtime error** - _Unable to cast object of type_ which is runtime not compile..(**?**)

Comment: @BenKnoble or  to be  more accurate `System.InvalidCastException`

Comment: I misread i think (or the edit fixed it) it looked like you said it didnt compile but instead threw a runtime... :P oops

Comment: @BenKnoble I've removed unsuitable `virtual` kw from props,  when added `sealed` kw to last descendant type, maybe that was problem of compile time virtual not suitable to sealed..

Comment: Have you tried using the `as` operator and checking for null?

Comment: @BenKnoble as with your last comment on `as` **you have solved it** (and btw value to cast from was not null i usually make sure ahead, and not using null checks) please post the correct answer elaborating on the reason as it is really important to now that _small_ issue

Comment: I posted a quick workaround with as; i cant elaborate on __why__ its happening as i dont know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure of the precise reasons a cast from `Derived` to `MoreDerived` fails here. However, a potential workaround (note: possibly code smell) is the `as` operator:

```
public static MoreDerived AsMoreDerived (this Derived d)
{
    return d as MoreDerived;
}
```

Note that `as` effectively attempts the cast and returns null, so you'll need an appropriate check there.

Comment: sorry for the early cheering comment on solved, as it now does not throw an exception, while parent type-value  is with data, subtype returns without i.e `null`

Comment: @Robb_2015  Are there fields in `MoreDerived` not present in `Derived`? Your extension method may need to copy fields, and then initialize any other fields instead of doing a simple cast.

Comment: i am terribly terribly sorry about my mistake!! i WAS indeed confused here , the reason of my problem in code is, when loading a new element into the generic collection i have created an `AddParDef()`   which was adding a new () parentType instead of derived into the `ParDefSet`(Collection) so no wonder that it couldn't be casted / converted into subType, so now the usual `(SubType)Parent` DownCast / Conversion does apply  . thanks alot for your effort, it did bring me to the answer and really helped !

Comment: Your very welcome @Robb_2015! Sometimes you just need a "rubber duck" to talk to :P

Comment: As a side note, after tonight @Robb_2015 should be Robb_2016

Comment: yes.. you're  funny(:,   and i have to make a new `RobCs` Helpers namespace file **RobCs61a.cs**, 6-> 2016 ,1-> January, a-> week 1